# Simplifying $\left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right\arrowvert_{z+\Delta z} - \left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right\arrowvert_{z} = ?$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am deriving a partial differential equation for wave in a string. $f$ represents displacement of the string at point $z$. I am stuck at a step.

Can anyone help me, how $ \left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right\arrowvert_{z+\Delta z} - \left.\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z} \right\arrowvert_{z} $ can be reduced to $  \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2} \Delta z$ ?

Comment: Please avoid titles that are entirely in $\TeX$. Thanks.

Comment: @ J.M.: Ok. I got it. Will take care in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(z)=\frac{∂f}{∂z}|_z$. So we have $g(z+\Delta{z})-g(z)=\frac{∂g}{∂z}\Delta{z}=\frac{∂^2f}{∂z^2}\Delta{z}$.

Sincerely,

Tigran